# Change color of child elements with the onclick event of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 3 `<a>` tags with each having class `categoryItem` wrapped inside of their respective parents with each having class `categoryLists`.

What I want is to have `a` tag of color red when li is clicked. For eg: If first li is clicked then it should only color the first `a` tag instead of coloring all of the `a` tags.

I tried using `for` loop but it doesn't seem to work as it colors the whole elements having `a` tags.

```js
function changeColor() {
    let catItem = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryItem');
    for(let i = 0; i < catItem.length; i++) {
      catItem[i].style.setProperty('color', 'red', 'important');
    }
}
```

```css
.categoryItem {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor()">First
  <a href="#" class="categoryItem">First Link</a>
</li>
<li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor()">Second
  <a href="#" class="categoryItem">Second Link</a>
</li>
<li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor()">Third
  <a href="#" class="categoryItem">Third Link</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Your anchor tags arent children of the li tags, also your html is invalid as li are supposed to be children of a ol or ul. This may cause problems in the future if browsers decide to do proper html corrections

Comment: @PatrickEvans This is just for test.

Comment: Well even as an example you need to have the html the way you are going to need it. As your problem describes a parent / child element situation and none of the elements are neither a parent or a child of each other.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Forgot to wrap the `a` tag inside of `li` tag :P ! Just edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. No need for ids:

```js
function changeColor(el) {       
  el.querySelector('a.categoryItem').style.setProperty('color', 'red', 'important');
}
```

```css
.categoryItem {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor(this)">First
     <a  href="#" class="categoryItem">First Link</a>
   </li>
   <li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor(this)">Second
     <a href="#" class="categoryItem">Second Link</a>
   </li>
   <li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor(this)">Third
     <a href="#" class="categoryItem">Third Link</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If only you tell me to add those ids dynamically.

Comment: Now is dynamic @Sanjay I've edited the answer based on your Edit of the question.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Pass `this` to your inline js function call that way your function will have a reference to the element that was clicked.

```
onclick="changeColor(this)"
```

Then use `querySelector()` or similar DOM method to get the child anchor tag of that element.

```
var item = listElement.querySelector('a.categoryItem');
```

And from there do the necessary manipulation, note using css classes instead of direct style manipulation.

```
item.classList.remove('active')
```

Demo

```js
function changeColor(listElement) {
  //clear the active class from current active
  var active = listElement.parentElement.querySelector('a.categoryItem.active');
  if(active){
    active.classList.remove('active');
  }

  //set the class of the newly clicked element.
  var item = listElement.querySelector('a.categoryItem');
  if (item) {
    item.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.categoryItem {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}

.categoryItem.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor(this)">First
    <a href="#" class="categoryItem">First Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor(this)">Second
    <a href="#" class="categoryItem">Second Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="categoryList" onclick="changeColor(this)">Third
    <a href="#" class="categoryItem">Third Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome. Got it